# -> operator in the middle of a property

Tags: system-verilog, asic

I understand that `[-> m]` is a non-consecutive GoTo operator and can be used as (e.g.)

```
@(posedge clk) a |=> b [->2] ##1 c;
```

But I came across an example, where I see (in the middle of a property), `a -> b`. What does that mean? Does it mean if `a` is true that `b` is true? Does it behave like an overlapping implication operator? Please see the example below. Thanks.

```
property count_event(reg [15:0] PerfCtr, reg [15:0] event_count);

 
@(posedge DfiClk)

disable iff (disable_perfcntcheck)

((PWR_OK === 1'b1) && (Reset === 1'b0) && (DebugPerfCtrEn === 1) && (dfi_event_select === 1) && ($rose(dfi_event))) |->

##[1:5] !$isunknown(capture_dly) && (**!capture_dly -> event_count == PerfCtr**) ##1 !$isunknown(capture_dly) && (**capture_dly -> event_count == PerfCtr**);
```

Comment: And if you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is in the middle of a logical expression, not *property*. It is the `logical implication` operator:

11.4.7 Logical operators

> The logical implication expression1 –> expression2 is logically equivalent to
> (!expression1 || expression2), and the logical equivalence expression1 <–> expression2 is
> logically equivalent to ((expression1 –> expression2) && (expression2 –> expression1)).
> Each of the two operands of the logical equivalence operator shall be evaluated exactly once.